# How to trigger Facebook photo verification?

Tags: facebook, security

I would like to trigger photo verification for my own account. It is said that Facebook gives you a bunch of photos to identify if you log in from an unknown or new location. I have already tried to use proxies, VPNs and Tor but despite the fact that I use my Facebook from only 2 locations/networks regularly I did not manage to trigger verification.

Comment: It may not have rolled out to you or your country. That's my best guess. Or they got too many complaints and killed the feature.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to trigger photo verification apart from actually use case where the scenario is necessary such as

**2500 miles Montreal,Qc,Canada to Trinidad and Tobago,Caribbean**
I was helping my sibling (in Trinidad and Tobago) with a problem on Facebook from Montreal,QC by logging into his account.

**2300 miles approx Montreal,Qc,Canada to Portland,OR USA**
Visited a friend and logged in via his computer.

So with these two cases I believe its based on time/distance between places. If I log in at place X but then log in to place Y only Z minutes after (first case) miles away (second case) then I receive the verification process. This only works on the initial log in. Any activity that follows seems to be okay for me.

These two cases happened in 2010. The algorithm may have changed since then.

*Summary: If there was a way to trigger it manually then that just increases the number of false positives for this security feature*